# If the product of two numbers is nonnegative than either both are nonnegative or both are nonpositive

Tags: inequality, real-numbers, axioms

In trying to prove the following inequality: $0\leq ab\Longrightarrow (0\leq a\wedge 0\leq b)\vee(a\leq 0\wedge b\leq 0)$ the following proof by contradiction was tried

Proof:
Let $0\leq ab$ and let,$\neg (0\leq a\wedge 0\leq b)$ and $\neg(a\leq 0\wedge b\leq 0)$. But $\neg(a\leq 0\wedge b\leq 0)\Longrightarrow \neg(a\leq 0)\vee\neg(b\leq 0)\Longrightarrow 0<a\vee o<b$. For $o<a\Longrightarrow\frac{1}{a}$. Also $0<a\Longrightarrow 0\leq a$. Thus $0\leq ab\wedge 0<\frac{1}{a}\Longrightarrow 0(\frac{1}{a})< ab(\frac{1}{a})\Longrightarrow 0<b\Longrightarrow  0\leq b$.  Therefore $0\leq a\wedge 0\leq b$.

For $0<b$ we also can prove in the same way $0\leq a\wedge 0\leq b$. Hence $0\leq a\wedge 0\leq b$ a contradiction since we assumed $\neg(0\leq a\wedge 0\leq b)$. Thus we have $0\leq a\wedge 0\leq b$. But $(o\leq a\wedge 0\leq b)\Longrightarrow (0\leq a\wedge 0\leq b)\vee(a\leq 0\wedge b\leq 0)$

Comment: Unreadable. Spaces after punctuation, paragraph breaks, more English, less symbols.

Comment: Which sentence(s) Is (are) unreadable??

Comment: The symbols used in the above proof are: 1) The mathematical symbols: $\leq$,$<$,$\frac$, and that of multiplication. 2) The logical symbols $\wedge$,$\Longrightarrow$,,$\vee$,$\neg$

Comment: So is this an exercise in how to write symbolic logic or do you seriously want advise on how to prove only products of two positives or two negatives are positive?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you're doing from the point you introduce $1/a$.

You've shown that $¬(a≤0∧b≤0)$ is equivalent to $a>0∨b>0$.

Similarly $¬(0≤a∧0≤b)$ is equivalent to $a<0∨b<0$.

So we're left with $¬(0≤a∧0≤b)$  and $¬(a≤0∧b≤0)$

is equivalent to:

$(a<0∨b<0)$ and $(a>0∨b>0)$. From here just show that $ab<0$, and you've obtained the contradiction.

EDIT: here's a full answer

$(a<0∨b<0) ∧ (a>0∨b>0) \\\iff 
(a<0∧a>0)∨(a<0∧b>0)∨(b<0∧a>0)∨(b<0∧b>0) \\\implies 
(a<0∧a\ge0)∨(ab<0)∨(ab<0)∨(b<0∧b\ge0) \\\iff
((a<0)∧\neg(a<0))∨(ab<0)∨((b<0∧\neg(b<0)) \\\iff
F∨(ab<0)∨F  \\\iff
ab<0$

Comment: $(a<o\vee b<0)$ and $(0<a\vee 0<b)$ is equivalent to $(a<0\wedge 0<a)\vee (a<o\wedge 0<b)\vee(b<0\wedge 0<a)\vee(b<0\wedge 0<b)$ which is equivalent to  $(a<0\wedge 0<a)\vee ab<0\vee ab<0\vee (b<0\wedge 0<b)$. Now where is the contradiction

Comment: Using T is true and F is false, $(a<0∧a>0)$ is always false. $(b<0∧0<b)$ is always false. So the expression simplifies to $F∨ab<0∨ab<0∨F$ which simplifies to $ab<0$

Comment: That is a semantical proof that we never use in mathematical proofs. The proofs in Mathematics are syntactical in nature. Should you find a single mathematical book using semantical proofs in developing their content, let me know. Furthermore in the proposition calculus proofs using false or true belong to its semantical part. It shows weakness in mathematical reasoning if one escapes into a semantical proof.

Comment: Well, you can easily convert it into a syntatical proof right? which part do you object to? The use of T and F... that's tautology and contradiction, and it's used in symbolic logic constantly... or 0 and 1 are used. But I avoided that here since we're already using 0 and 1.

Comment: How do you prove ,then syntacticaly that,$(a<0\wedge 0<a)\vee ab<0\vee ab<0\vee (b<0\wedge 0<b)$ implies $ab<0$. i mean without using the true or false concept

Comment: I've updated my answer, but I'm still using the T=tautology and F=contradiction. I don't understand why you object to this though. Do you object to these types of logic: $b∨a∧\neg a \iff b ∨ F \iff b$, and $b ∨ a∨\neg a \iff b ∨ T \iff T$

Comment: That means that you do not know how to prove purely syntacticaly :$b\vee(a\wedge\neg a) \Longleftrightarrow b$ ,without using the $b\vee F$ in between